# Unicode characters in "LABEL ON" statement - AS400/DB2

Tags: sql, unicode, db2, label, ibm-midrange

I would like to put a unicode character inside a "LABEL ON" statement in AS400. It gives me the following error:

`[Error Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  [SQL0104] Token UX'0171' was not valid. Valid tokens: <CHARSTRING>. Cause . . . . . :   A syntax error was detected at token UX'0171'.  Token UX'0171' is not a valid token.  A partial list of valid tokens is <CHARSTRING>.  This list assumes that the statement is correct up to the token.  The error may be earlier in the statement, but the syntax of the statement appears to be valid up to this point. Recovery  . . . :   Do one or more of the following and try the request again: -- Verify the SQL statement in the area of the token UX'0171'. Correct the statement.  The error could be a missing comma or quotation mark, it could be a misspelled word, or it could be related to the order of clauses. -- If the error token is <END-OF-STATEMENT>, correct the SQL statement because it does not end with a valid clause.`

The statement is:

`LABEL ON COLUMN TABLENAME.COLUMNNAME IS 'ű';`

"ű" is a Hungarian double acute letter, Unicode is U+0171. It also throws an error on the other double acute letter "ő" (U+0151). It does not throw an error on less special characters, like single acute letters (áéíóúöü).

IBM page on "LABEL ON" statement has no specifics to character codes, it only mentions the length of the label.

I tried inserting text with this character in a random text column in the database and it had no problem insterting (though it had displaying, but that is less of a problem now).

I also read somewhere that the AS400 has many names, which makes it difficult to search for answers.

Is there a way to make it possible to enter such special unicode characters inside a "LABEL ON" statement in AS400?

Comment: Labels are stored using default CCSID (CCSID 37). It is not possible to enter special unicode characters for columns defined with CCSID 37. Check link for acceptable characters for CCSID 37. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_037

Answer (score 0):

The LABEL ON syntax for column labels is:
[image: LABEL ON Selected syntax tree]

According to the documentation of an SQL String Constant (found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzcharconst.htm)):

> Character-string constants can contain mixed data. If the job CCSID supports mixed data, a character-string constant is classified as mixed data if it includes a DBCS substring. In all other cases, a character-string constant is classified as SBCS data.
>
> The CCSID assigned to the constant is the CCSID of the SQL statement text containing the constant unless the SQL statement is encoded in Unicode or a foreign encoding scheme (such as ASCII). In this case, the SQL statement text is converted from Unicode or the foreign encoding scheme to the default CCSID of the current server. The CCSID assigned to the constant will be the default CCSID of the current server1.

So string constants will be treated as DBCS or SBCS strings depending on your server's default CCSID (not necessarily 37). You can't insert Unicode into a label. If the character you want to use is in your default CCSID, then you can add it as a hex value if it isn't on your keyboard. Otherwise you are out of luck. Inserting data into the database is a different story.